# How to prove that the topological spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let's consider a topological space $X$. We define $X \times I / {\sim}$ as a product of $X$ and a $I=[0, 1]$ closed interval's  quotient by the following equivalence relation: $(x, 1) \sim (y, 1), (x, 0) \sim (y, 0)$, $\alpha_{1} \neq \{0, 1 \}$, $(x, \alpha_{1}) \sim (y, \alpha_{2}) \leftrightarrow (x=y) \wedge (\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2})$

Informally speaking, if we consider $X = \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and denote $Y= \mathbb{S}^{1} \times [0, 1]/ {\sim}$ we see that it looks like a two glued cones,which have a common basement.

The problem is to show that $\mathbb{S}^{n} \times I / {\sim}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$.

The trouble is that to cope with it rigorously. The common approach is to try looking for  a bijection, which is continous and its inverse is also so, but this doesn't looks as a more or less general method, which enables to solve various problems, requiring homeomorphysm's proof. Also, sometimes it is possible to apply a quotient universal property, which tell us the answer without explicit building of a map.

The questions are:
1) How can we prove that two spaces are homeomophic without building an exact map?

2) How to prove that two spaces are NOT homeomorpic, but thier fundamental groups are isomorphic (without applying other homotopy groups). (sometimes it's possible to notice that one is compact/connected and the second is not but not always)

3) How to find the approach to the exact problem, which is described above?

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can define a specific mapping in this case.   Mapping the equivalence class $[(x,1)]$ to the North pole, and the class $[(x,-1)]$ to the south pole.  The points $(x,a)$, with $|a|<1$  must be mapped continuously to sphere minus the poles.  Check my work, but  $(x,a) \mapsto  ( (1-a^2)x,  a)$  seems to glue it together correctly.

Comment: 1) I don't know *any* way to show that two spaces are homeomorphic without building an explicit map. Sometimes you have theorems that say things like "If two spaces are [property], then they must be homeomorphic", but the chain of inference here, in *every* case I know, builds an explicit map somewhere in the process. 2) This is impossibly broad. Examples: There are other homotopy invariants like homology; you can find some other topological property that is useful here, like local connectedness or something; maybe you can build some complicated invariant, like rational pontryagin classes.

Comment: 3) By writing down an explicit homeomorphism. Do it in the case of $X = S^1$ or even $X = S^0$ first if you need inspiration.

Comment: @MikeMiller For example, i want to prove that $\mathbb{S}^{1} \approx \mathbb{S}^{1} / (x \sim -x, \forall x)$.
Considering a map $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1}$: $f(z)=z^{2}$ i claim that it's continous and surjective. Also, $f(z)=f(-z)$, then it identifies the opposite points on sphere. Then by the universal property of the quotient, there exists a homeomorphism such that $\varphi: \mathbb{S}^{1} / \sim \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1}$.

Comment: You just constructed the homeomorphism. It's what $f$ descends to: $f(\{-z, z\}) = z^2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Actually, yes, now i see that  it does describe the process of the homomorphysm's building,